# page load from javascript

Tags: javascript

i m building a website in asp.net using c#..
can nyone tell me ..is it possible to either call a pageload function or load a page from javascript

Comment: I think you might want to add more detail to this question. Do you want to call the server side page load method? Or do you want to call a javascript method once the page has loaded in the browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

[window.location](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Window.location)

> Returns a  Location object, which
>   contains information about the URL of
>   the document and provides methods for
>   changing that URL. You can also assign
>   to this property to load another URL.

Comment: actually i want to load the same page from javascript,,it means i have to give the url of that page only

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to go to another page like from yourpage.com to example.com?

If yes, you can use `location.href="http://example.com"` in javascript.

Answer (score 0):

you can call __dopostback javascript method:

```
__doPostBack('ControlId','');
```

http://aspalliance.com/895_Understanding_the_JavaScript___doPostBack_Function.all

Answer (score 0):

```
window.location.reload()
```

And just for future reference, you could have found that in 10 seconds by Googling "javascript reload".